# Modeling Class Schedules in SQL

Tags: sql, associations

I’m trying to model a class schedule and having a hard time thinking through what tables and associations I should have in a SQL db. Here is the data I’m trying to persist:

1. Class (e.g, “Art Class”)
2. Schedule

The schedule is where things get a bit complicated. A class can last a semester (i.e, 6 months, two days a week, 9-10am one day and 11-12pm another) or a one time class (this Monday at 11am).

I have a class table but unsure how to best model the schedule.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest listing all the days explicitly.  So you would have a table called, say, `classSchedules` that has columns for:

- `classid`
- `startDatetime`
- `endDatetime`

There would be a separate row for each day (assuming that classes do not meet more than once per day).